# Puma MiniSSL SSLError OpenSSL error while running the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, puma

This error shows up while running the rails server

```
[18560] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[18560] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[18560] * Min threads: 10, max threads: 10
[18560] * Environment: development
[18560] * Process workers: 1
[18560] * Phased restart available
[18560] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
[18560] * Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?cert=config/ssl.crt&key=config/ssl.key&verify_mode=none&no_tlsv1=false&no_tlsv1_1=false
[18560] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[18560] * Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1603431286007-18560
[18560] - Worker 0 (pid: 19322) booted, phase: 0
2020-10-23 11:05:30 +0530: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher - 337092801>
```

I saw similar posts here but could not find any satisfactory answer that could correct this error.